# How to change keyboard keymap

Tags: debian, keyboard

I accidentally set my keyboard type to US during installation, but it actually is UK type. How do I change it?

[**note**] I use Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Debian way is:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

To make the change visible in X (else reboot):

```
/etc/init.d/hal restart
```

Comment: Regarding HAL, which version of Debian are you talking about? AFAIR X in Squeeze doesn't need HAL.

Comment: The HAL part is optional, just reboot your X server.